# Dictionary for converting a powershell (.ps1) code to bash (.sh)

Tags: bash, powershell

I made a .ps1 code, purpose being to run java files quickly in a single line. I have it in powershell code (.ps1) but I want to convert it to bash code (.sh) that can run on both OSX and Linux (I unfortunately do not have linux or unix machines on hand to test it, and I know that is far from ideal).

My code is:

```
# This whole IF/ELSE is used to make sure jrun.ps1 runs to the right path. 
$originalPath="Nah"
if ($args[0] -eq '--path') { 
    $path=$args[1]
    $name=$args[2]
    $originalPath=Get-Location

    $argstopass=$args[3..($args.Count-1)]

    Set-Location $path
} elseif ($args[0] -eq '-p') { 
    $path=$args[1]
    $name=$args[2]
    $originalPath=Get-Location

    $argstopass=$args[3..($args.Count-1)]

    Set-Location $path
} else {
    $name=$args[0]
    $argstopass=$args[1..($args.Count-1)]
}

if (-Not $args[0]) {
    'Please provide an input.'
    exit
}


' '
'----------------'
' '
'Jrun:'
'    javac-ing'
try {
    $javacReturned = javac ($name+'.java') 2>&1 | Out-String
    if ($LASTEXITCODE) {
        Throw
    }
}
catch {
    '    A Compile Error ocurred.'
    if ($originalPath -ne "Nah") { 
        Set-Location $originalPath
    }
    ''
    '    The error message:'
    ''
    $javacReturned
    exit
}

try {
    '    java-ing'
    ' '
    '----------------'
    ' '
    ('Response from running ' + $name + ': ')
    ' '
    $javareturned = java $name $argstopass
    $javareturned
    ' '
} catch {
    '    A Runtime Error ocurred.'
    if ($originalPath -ne "Nah") { 
        Set-Location $originalPath
    }
    ''
    '    The error message:'
    ''
    $javaReturned
    exit
}



if ($originalPath -ne "Nah") { 
    Set-Location $originalPath
}
```

And I know it may not work properly if there is a folder called "Nah" in the current working directory, but I do not plan to send this code to many people, and the users will know of this bug.

I want to convert this to bash, is there a good inter-language dictionary that I can use? I don't particularly want to rewrite the code without a convenient machine.

P.s. I'm new to Stack overflow, lmk if I should word the question differently.

Comment: Did you consider to install PowerShell 7 on your Linux machines so you don't need to convert your script?

Comment: @Alex_P, I actually can't install Powershell on the osx/unix machine; that's why I need to convert the code.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is not a really a PowerShell code issue/error, but you are asking folks to help you rewrite a Powershell script into another language, which has nothing to do with PowerShell and specifically because you don't have access to a *nix/OSX environment. Thus would lead one to assume you really don't know Bash either. So, you are literally asking folks to do your work for you.

That is not what we are here to do...

Stackoverflow rules:

> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
>
> [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
>
> [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

... though every once in a while a very kind person might...

[Converting PowerShell to Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145333/converting-powershell-to-bash)

There are several sites, that provide free tools for you to mess with bash online.

Nothing stops you from installing/enabling [WSL (Windows Services for Linux)](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%20install%20WSL&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=windows%20install%20wsl&sc=3-19&sk=&cvid=256E254C371D4F17B1760A1399794633) and a Linux distro on your Win10 device. [It's actually built into the Win 10 OS features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), and thus allowing you to run/use Bash.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have not idea what a [banhammer] is, not do I think I'd want. It sounds painful. ;-}. SO rules are SO rules, I have nothing to do with those. Yet, there is no dictionary thingy to convert PS to Bash. It's a manual effort. [There are several sites that talk about such things](https://www.bing.com/search?q=compare+powershell+and+bash+commands&form=ANSPH1&refig=789b9028f92a48df83330d1d5a6474c4&sp=-1&pq=compare+powershell+and+bash+command&sc=0-35&qs=n&sk=&cvid=789b9028f92a48df83330d1d5a6474c4).